# How can I create a new column that groups variables from an existing column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which includes a column of data (X1_What_site_are_you) on study site. There are 8 factors. I want to create a new column that groups these factors by their habitat type with 4 factors representing woodland sites (Mann's Copse 1, Mann's Copse 2, Nash's Copse 1, Nash's Copse 2) and 4 factors representing field sites (Nash's Field 1, Nash's Field 2, Nursery Field 1, Nursery Field 2).

Here is the data structure:

```
'data.frame':   560 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ title                            : chr  "Mann's Copse 1 18/02/2021" "Mann's Copse 1 18/02/2021" "Mann's Copse 1 18/02/2021" "Mann's Copse 1 18/02/2021" ...
 $ X1_What_site_are_you_            : Factor w/ 8 levels "Mann's Copse 1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lat_2_What_are_the_GPS_c         : num  51.4 51.4 51.4 51.4 51.4 ...
 $ long_2_What_are_the_GPS_c        : num  -0.653 -0.653 -0.653 -0.653 -0.653 ...
 $ accuracy_2_What_are_the_GPS_c    : int  27 27 27 27 27 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ UTM_Northing_2_What_are_the_GPS_c: int  5698309 5698309 5698309 5698309 5698309 5698310 5698310 5698310 5698310 5698310 ...
 $ UTM_Easting_2_What_are_the_GPS_c : int  663238 663238 663238 663238 663238 663239 663239 663239 663239 663239 ...
 $ UTM_Zone_2_What_are_the_GPS_c    : chr  "30U" "30U" "30U" "30U" ...
 $ X3_What_date_is_it               : chr  "18/02/2021" "18/02/2021" "18/02/2021" "18/02/2021" ...
 $ X4_What_time_is_it               : chr  "17:15:02" "17:15:02" "17:15:02" "17:15:02" ...
 $ X5_What_are_your_init            : chr  "JAJ" "JAJ" "JAJ" "JAJ" ...
 $ Count                            : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ robinalarm                       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ robincall                        : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 4 4 3 ...
 $ robinsound                       : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 4 5 3 ...
 $ birdsight                        : int  24 0 0 0 0 24 0 1 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

```
 ##CREATE HABITAT COLUMN  
birds["Habitat"] <- rep(0, 560)
     # Run a for loop 
for (i in 1:nrow(birds)){
  if (str_detect(birds[i, 2], "Copse") == "TRUE"){
    birds[i, 17] <- "Forest". 
  }
  else {
    birds[i, 17] <- "Grassland"
  }
}
```

- In this example set the rep to the number of columns in the dataset (e.g. `rep(0,x)`)
- Where `str_detect(birds[i,2],` the 2 represents the column number from which the factors sit
- Where `birds[i,17]` the 17 represents the new columns to which the new grouping variables are input